# Nothing was returned from render but I cant figure out why

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Circular-Progressbar Repository on github to design a dashboard for my site but when I am trying to run it. I get an error that states:

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Circle(...): Nothing was returned from
>   render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to
>   render nothing, return null. I cannot figure out why.

**Circle.js File is rendered in my main App file**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {CircularProgressbar,buildStyles} from "react-circular-progressbar";
import { easeQuadInOut } from "d3-ease";
import AnimatedProgressProvider from "./AnimatedProgressProvider";
import 'react-circular-progressbar/dist/styles.css';

class Circle extends Component{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state={
            category:"",
            percentage:""
        };
    }

    render(){
        <AnimatedProgressProvider valueStart={0} valueEnd={66} duration={1.4} easingFunction={easeQuadInOut}>
          {(value) => {
            const roundedValue = Math.round(value);
            return (
              <CircularProgressbar value={value} text={`${roundedValue}%`} styles={buildStyles({ pathTransition: 'none' })} />
            );
          }}
        </AnimatedProgressProvider>
      }
}

export default Circle;
```

**AnimatedProgressProvider.js File is used in Circle.js**

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import { Animate } from "react-move";

class AnimatedProgressProvider extends Component {
  interval = undefined;

  state = {
    isAnimated: false
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    valueStart: 0
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.repeat) {
      this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
        this.setState({
          isAnimated: !this.state.isAnimated
        });
      }, this.props.duration * 1000);
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isAnimated: !this.state.isAnimated
      });
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.clearInterval(this.interval);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Animate
        start={() => ({
          value: this.props.valueStart
        })}
        update={() => ({
          value: [
            this.state.isAnimated ? this.props.valueEnd : this.props.valueStart
          ],
          timing: {
            duration: this.props.duration * 1000,
            ease: this.props.easingFunction
          }
        })}
      >
        {({ value }) => this.props.children(value)}
      </Animate>
    );
  }
}

export default AnimatedProgressProvider;
```

Any help you all could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I assume, that problem here is that `this.props.children` is not should be used as just function. Never even saw such usage in react.

Comment: The `render` function of the `Circle` component is missing the `return` statement.

Comment: @Klimenkomud this is a common technique known as [_Render Props_](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

Comment: @EmileBergeron I guess, you miss my point: I never saw usage like `this.props.children(value)`. Other words, I never saw trying to access `props.children` as regular function

Comment: @EmileBergeron Thanks for you r comment Emile. Your comment worked! I just overlooked the placement of my original return function.

Comment: @Klimenkomud That's exactly what I'm responding to, `this.props.children(value)` is a type of Render Props technique, described in the link I shared above.

Comment: @EmileBergeron Are you sure? I didn't find any related info to such usage via that link. May you give me direct quote?

Comment: @Klimenkomud [Pretty sure](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render)

Comment: @EmileBergeron It doesn't make direct function call. It pass function as value for `render` prop(e.g. `children`), the first argument for it - is passed value as children. E.g. it doesn't make `<Mouse children={mouse => mouse()} />`, and that exactly what TS trying to do. Anyway, thanks for link

Comment: @Klimenkomud it does, and assumes that the reader understands that `Mouse.propTypes = { children: PropTypes.func.isRequired };` means calling `this.props.children(anything)` as a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to explicitly return the `JSX` inside `render`:

```
render(){
    return (
        <AnimatedProgressProvider valueStart={0} valueEnd={66} duration={1.4} easingFunction={easeQuadInOut}>
            {(value) => {
                const roundedValue = Math.round(value);
                return (
                    <CircularProgressbar value={value} text={`${roundedValue}%`} styles={buildStyles({ pathTransition: 'none' })} />
                );
            }}
        </AnimatedProgressProvider>
    )
}
```

Comment: WOW! Can't believe I missed this. I literally stared at this code for an hour but for some reason I didn't realize the return function I had was inside of my arrow function I just completely overlooked the need for a return inside render. Thank you for the quick reply on this. My code works perfectly now!

Comment: Sometime we just need an extra pair of eyes. xD Good luck!